# Why is save_post hook not running?

Tags: metabox, hooks, troubleshooting

I am trying to save my meta box, I have something like

```
function xxx_meta_box_callback() {
    add_meta_box('xxx-meta', 'xxx Details', 'xxx_meta_box', 'xxx-post-type', 'side', 'default');
    add_action('save_post', 'xxx_save_meta_box');
    error_log('meta box cb');
}

function xxx_save_meta_box($post_id, $post) {
    error_log('running ...');
    die('OK!!!');
}
```

I am getting "meta box cb" ok in my error log, but `xxx_save_meta_box()` does not seem to run. Why is that?

Comment: Why are you adding the `save_posts` callback from inside the metabox callback? I'd take a guess at that being the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in your theme's `functions.php` file, or a `.php` file of a plugin that you may be writing:

```
add_action('save_post', 'xxx_save_meta_box');
function xxx_meta_box_callback() {
  add_meta_box('xxx-meta','xxx Details','xxx_meta_box','xxx-post-type','side','default');
  error_log('meta box cb');
}
function xxx_save_meta_box($post_id, $post) {
  error_log('running ...');
  die('OK!!!');
}
```

Comment: Why does `add_action('save_post'` have to be on wp init?

Comment: It actually does not. When I answered this question I misunderstood this aspect of WordPress. I'm editing my answer.